# How can I redraw my jstree with new HTML data?

Tags: javascript, jstree

I have a list of category depending of the publication selected. I want to redraw my category tree depending of the publication selected.

I retrieve new html from the server everytime I select a new publication.

My HTML look like that :

```
<ul>
   <li id="27">
      Moto
      <ul>
         <li id="30">Route</li>
      </ul>
      <ul>
         <li id="31">Cross</li>
      </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
<ul>
   <li id="28">
      Limousine
      <ul>
         <li id="32">3 Portes</li>
      </ul>
      <ul>
         <li id="33">5 Portes</li>
      </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
<ul>
   <li id="36">Avis Mortuaire</li>
</ul>
<ul>
   <li id="49">
      Stellen
      <ul>
         <li id="71">Stellengesuche</li>
      </ul>
      <ul>
         <li id="72">Stellen</li>
      </ul>
      <ul>
         <li id="73">Stellenangebote</li>
      </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
<ul>
   <li id="48">
      Diverses
      <ul>
         <li id="62">Diverses</li>
      </ul>
      <ul>
         <li id="68">Lebenshilfe</li>
      </ul>
      <ul>
         <li id="69">Bekanntschaften</li>
      </ul>
      <ul>
         <li id="70">Direktverkauf/Fabrik-Läden</li>
      </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
<ul>
   <li id="105">Editorial-Anzeige</li>
</ul>
```

So then I try to do a `jq11.jstree.reference('categoryTree').redraw(true)` but I get an error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'className' of undefined`.

So I wonder how can I redraw my jstree with the new html I insert when I change my publication?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok finally I have found a way to do this by destroying the old DOM and instance [$.jstree.destroy ()](http://www.jstree.com/api/#/?q=jstree&f=$.jstree.destroy()).

So I just do this way `$.jstree.reference('categoryTree').destroy();` then rebuild my DOM `$('#categoryTree').html(...);` and then I recreate my jstree instance `$('#categoryTree').jstree({...})`

I hope this will help someone else.